# Google+ API always get my profile information on start of application and can't clear account information

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I started to add the Google+ API on my app but weird thing is that it always get my profile information even though I haven't clicked on my button for sign in yet on second run. I just followed the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) for implementation. and here's my code so far:

On Create I setup my ApiClient:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();
```

Then I have this code on my onStart I expected it to clear the last account logged in and then the mGoogleApiClient.connect(); part is needed for the resolveSignInError() which is I'm not sure on why:

```
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
```

For my button click listener I have this piece of code to start signup:

```
public void SignupWithGoogle(View view) {

        social_login = 0;
        if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(getBaseContext())==null){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Google Play services not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            //TODO Connect using google plus
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mSignInClicked = true;
                resolveSignInError();
                progressDialog.setMessage("Logging In");
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Logged Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

onStop I also tried to disconnect the user:

```
protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

    }
```

The other part is just the same with the Tutorial given as well as the part of integration. I get the user credentials for display after the onConnected:

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // We've resolved any connection errors.  mGoogleApiClient can be used to
        // access Google APIs on behalf of the user.
        mSignInClicked = false;

        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            String gplus_email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            if (gplus_email.length() > 0) {
                email.setText(gplus_email);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No email found. Please specify your email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }


    }
```

Now the credentials are being fetched after I click the Google+ button but problem is after I close the app and re-lauch it the email is still there wherein it should not be present unless I clicked on the Google+ button again. I'm not sure on where did I miss but I hope someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try revoking the access tokens and disconnecting the app?

```
// Prior to disconnecting, run clearDefaultAccount().
Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

  onResult(Status status) {
    // mGoogleApiClient is now disconnected and access has been revoked.
    // Trigger app logic to comply with the developer policies
  }

})
```